# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when using bot to send notification to a known user at local test

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to use bot framework to send a user notification from my local loaded Teams tab

1. I created the bot and deployed to Azure
2. The bot works fine with the sample code to reply whatever user sent to it.
3. But when I tried to use a button (I wrote this to test sending notifications) in the Teams tab to trigger an Event that sending a notification to user, the console log showed me errors:

```
Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://c78cf14b.ngrok.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
VM27 bundle.js:160028 ERROR: ChatConnector: startConversation - error starting conversation.
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ VM27 bundle.js:160028
error @ VM27 bundle.js:30562
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:23677
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:24109
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:24198
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:24166
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:24160
tryCallOne @ VM27 bundle.js:32455
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:32541
flush @ VM27 bundle.js:11479
characterData (async)
requestCall @ VM27 bundle.js:11574
rawAsap @ VM27 bundle.js:11443
handleResolved @ VM27 bundle.js:32531
handle @ VM27 bundle.js:32527
finale @ VM27 bundle.js:32593
reject @ VM27 bundle.js:32589
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:32625
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:24152
self.callback @ VM27 bundle.js:176800
./node_modules/events/events.js.EventEmitter.emit @ VM27 bundle.js:55618
./node_modules/request/request.js.Request.onRequestError @ VM27 bundle.js:177496
./node_modules/events/events.js.EventEmitter.emit @ VM27 bundle.js:55618
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:210914
Promise rejected (async)
./node_modules/stream-http/lib/request.js.ClientRequest._onFinish @ VM27 bundle.js:210908
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:210813
./node_modules/events/events.js.EventEmitter.emit @ VM27 bundle.js:55615
finishMaybe @ VM27 bundle.js:172091
afterWrite @ VM27 bundle.js:171953
afterTick @ VM27 bundle.js:133523
./node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run @ VM27 bundle.js:133693
drainQueue @ VM27 bundle.js:133663
setTimeout (async)
runTimeout @ VM27 bundle.js:133581
./node_modules/process/browser.js.process.nextTick @ VM27 bundle.js:133683
nextTick @ VM27 bundle.js:133522
onwrite @ VM27 bundle.js:171941
WritableState.onwrite @ VM27 bundle.js:171641
./node_modules/stream-http/lib/request.js.ClientRequest._write @ VM27 bundle.js:211026
doWrite @ VM27 bundle.js:171889
writeOrBuffer @ VM27 bundle.js:171878
./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js.Writable.write @ VM27 bundle.js:171795
./node_modules/request/request.js.Request.write @ VM27 bundle.js:178115
end @ VM27 bundle.js:177164
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:177193
run @ VM27 bundle.js:198280
runIfPresent @ VM27 bundle.js:198309
onGlobalMessage @ VM27 bundle.js:198349
postMessage (async)
registerImmediate @ VM27 bundle.js:198360
setImmediate @ VM27 bundle.js:198267
./node_modules/request/request.js.Request.init @ VM27 bundle.js:177138
Request @ VM27 bundle.js:176742
request @ VM27 bundle.js:173150
refreshingToken.Promise.catch._this.refreshingToken @ VM27 bundle.js:24138
tryCallTwo @ VM27 bundle.js:32463
doResolve @ VM27 bundle.js:32618
Promise @ VM27 bundle.js:32484
./node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js.ChatConnector.refreshAccessToken @ VM27 bundle.js:24126
./node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js.ChatConnector.getAccessToken @ VM27 bundle.js:24165
./node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js.ChatConnector.addAccessToken @ VM27 bundle.js:24189
./node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js.ChatConnector.authenticatedRequest @ VM27 bundle.js:24078
./node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js.ChatConnector.startConversation @ VM27 bundle.js:23653
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:25581
./node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js.UniversalBot.tryCatch @ VM27 bundle.js:25654
./node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js.UniversalBot.ensureConversation @ VM27 bundle.js:25575
async.eachLimit.errorLogger._this.tryCatch.channelId @ VM27 bundle.js:25340
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:31303
replenish @ VM27 bundle.js:31441
(anonymous) @ VM27 bundle.js:31452
./node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js.async.forEachLimit.async.eachLimit @ VM27 bundle.js:31342
./node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js.UniversalBot.send @ VM27 bundle.js:25339
HomePage.buttonClicked @ VM27 bundle.js:220799
BaseButton._this._onClick @ VM27 bundle.js:99242
callCallback @ VM27 bundle.js:138209
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ VM27 bundle.js:138259
invokeGuardedCallback @ VM27 bundle.js:138316
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ VM27 bundle.js:138330
executeDispatch @ VM27 bundle.js:138621
executeDispatchesInOrder @ VM27 bundle.js:138643
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ VM27 bundle.js:138740
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ VM27 bundle.js:138748
forEachAccumulated @ VM27 bundle.js:138722
runEventsInBatch @ VM27 bundle.js:138876
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ VM27 bundle.js:138884
handleTopLevel @ VM27 bundle.js:142880
batchedUpdates$1 @ VM27 bundle.js:156992
batchedUpdates @ VM27 bundle.js:140210
dispatchEvent @ VM27 bundle.js:142959
interactiveUpdates$1 @ VM27 bundle.js:157047
interactiveUpdates @ VM27 bundle.js:140229
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ VM27 bundle.js:142936
VM27 bundle.js:160028 TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

code snippet:

```
    private buttonClicked = () => {
        const address =
        {
            channelId: 'msteams',
            user: { id: '{myUserId}' },
            channelData: {
                tenant: {
                    id: '{myTenantId}'
                }
            },
            notification: {
                alert: true
            },
            bot:
            {
                id: '{mybotid}',
                name: 'Test Bot'
            },
            serviceUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/'
        }
        const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
            appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
            appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
        });
        const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
        const msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
        msg.text('Hello, this is a notification');
        msg.summary('This is  a summary');
        bot.send(msg);
    }
```

Looks like I need to set up Bearer token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-conversation-members

But how should I set up this when sending message?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please share the ngrok command you are using? Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Hi Wajeed. Yes, it is still a issue, and I deployed the bot to azure.

Answer (score 0):

You're setup is a little bit of a mystery to understand, but it *sounds* like you are trying to connect a locally run instance of Teams to your Azure deployed bot via ngrok. If that is the case, then you need to enable CORS on your bot to accept your localhost address.

To do this, open your Azure resource group for you deployed bot. Then, select the App Service

[image]

Next, on the left menu, scroll down to the API section and select 'CORS'

[image]

Finally,

- Check the 'Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' checkbox, and
- Add your localhost address to the list
- Click Save

Read the instructions listed above the checkbox if your localhost changes often (this is likely the case if you use the free ngrok service).

Hope of help!

Comment: I configured it like what you said, but I still get same CORS error message.

Comment: @LifeiWang, apologies - I just saw your response. Are you still having an issue with this?